Custom attribute isnt found during test collection ordering - xunit
Im running E2E tests with some of the logics written using xUnit (.NET 8, c#) and need the tests to run in particular order. Id like to control the order in 2 ways: test case and class - and it needs to be ordered by numbers (int that is).
This is the test case attribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TestCaseOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; }

    public TestCaseOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}

and this is the class level attribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestClassOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; }

    public TestClassOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}

This is the test case orderer:
public class TestCaseOrderer: ITestCaseOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<TTestCase> OrderTestCases<TTestCase>(IEnumerable<TTestCase> testCases) where TTestCase : ITestCase
    {
        return testCases.OrderBy(tc =>
        {
            var orderAttribute = tc.TestMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCaseOrderAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
            return orderAttribute?.GetNamedArgument<int>("Order") ?? 0;
        });
    }
}

and this is the class orderer:
public class TestCollectionOrderer : ITestCollectionOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<ITestCollection> OrderTestCollections(IEnumerable<ITestCollection> testCollections)
    {
        return testCollections.OrderBy(tc =>
        {
            var classOrderAttribute = tc.CollectionDefinition.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassOrderAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
            return classOrderAttribute?.GetNamedArgument<int>("Order") ?? 0;
        });
    }
}

ALL are defined in some infra project in my solution.
this is the collection definition - defined in my test project (meaning the attributes and orderers are in a different project):
[CollectionDefinition("TestCollection")]
public class BasicTestCollectionDefinition: ICollectionFixture<LinuxBasicFixture>
{
}

This is my assemblyInfo of the test project:
[assembly: TestCollectionOrderer("Infra.TestOrder.Orderers.TestCollectionOrders.TestCollectionOrderer", "Infra")]
[assembly: TestCaseOrderer("Infra.TestOrder.Orderers.TestCaseOrders.TestCaseOrderer", "Infra")]
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]

and finally - these are my sample tests:
[Collection("TestCollection"), TestClassOrder(2)]
[Trait("test_name", "update_installation")]
public class PingTest
{
    public PingTest(ILogger<UpdateTest> logger, LinuxBasicFixture fixture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running PingTest linux test");
    }
    
    [Fact, TestCaseOrder(2)]
    public void Ping_ShouldSucceed_Second()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
    
    [Fact, TestCaseOrder(1)]
    public void Ping_ShouldSucceed()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}

while the ordering of the test cases is working as expected - the class attributes arent found. meaning the line in the test collection orderer var classOrderAttribute = tc.CollectionDefinition.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassOrderAttribute)).FirstOrDefault(); returns null.
The test case attr and orderer and the test collection attr and orderer are written just almost the same as you can see. No matter what i tried and what I read in here and the xUnit docs - i couldnt find what im missing. I looked at this lib (https://github.com/tomaszeman/Xunit.Extensions.Ordering/tree/master) and couldnt find anything im doing different than what its author did - and yet im missing something. I dont want to use the mentioned lib as it is not well maintained.
would appreciate any help!
EDIT:
1 - i found that if i added the attribute to the CollecitionDefinition class - the code finds it. which leads me to 2
2 - id like to state again - what i want is to control the order of test classes - not test collections!
3 - it seems that the test case orderer is aware of the test class - but its too late there - as the class was already accessed and now we sort the test cases.

You won't be able to solve this without implementing a custom XunitTestCollectionRunner, see how the NuGet package you're referring to has done it: https://github.com/tomaszeman/Xunit.Extensions.Ordering/blob/master/Xunit.Extensions.Ordering/TestCollectionRunner.cs#L46
